# Whitelisting Access to Office 365 as SaaS on Azure Cloud

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, office365

We are accessing the Office 365 mailbox as SaaS on Azure cloud from AWS VPC using MS Graph API. Please suggest options to whitelist access to Office 365 , so that it is accessible from only AWS VPC.

Comment: You may want to get started from this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/urls-and-ip-address-ranges?view=o365-worldwide

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity still looking for help. We attempted using conditional access feature of Azure Active directory , but it didn't help as it works only for interactive users and not for application logins.

Comment: Ok. If it doesn't work then i would suggest you to open a support ticket with Microsoft and they may help.